# How to concatenate multiple columns values into a single value per unique row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with data of the duplicate result set, like the column names and the values which caused the duplicates.

| ColName | ColValue | UniqueIDpercombination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KitiD | K89901 | 1 |
| Kit | 00900 | 1 |
| KitiD | L7865 | 2 |
| Kit | 00400 | 2 |
| UPC | 345234 | 3 |
| UPN | AVF | 3 |

...... and so on.

I would like to combine the colname and colvalues into a single row per uniqueID as shown in below table. The column name values are not fixed.

| ColName | ColValue | UniqueIDpercombination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KitiD - Kit | K89901 - 00900 | 1 |
| KitiD - Kit | L7865 - 00400 | 2 |
| UPC - UPN | 345234 AVF | 3 |

I tried using `stuff` with `xml path`, I did not get the desired output, below is the query which I tried and the output.

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT '-' + s.Colname +','  
        FROM ##resultset s 
         --group by uniqueidpercombination, colname
         FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, '' 
) AS colname 

,STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT '/' + s.colvalue
        FROM ##resultsets
         --group by uniqueidpercombination, colvalue
         FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
     1, 1, ''
) AS colvale
```

| ColName | ColValue |
| --- | --- |
| kitid-kit-kitid-kit | K89901-00900 -L7865-00400 |

Any suggestions on how to fix this?.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `STUFF` and `XML PATH` then `GROUP BY` the `UniqueIDpercombination` column.

You were close with your query, however, you need to `SELECT` from your table first, then use a `WHERE` clause in your subqueries to essentially `JOIN` your outer query with your inner subqueries with a `GROUP BY`. That way you won't return the entire table in one single row.

It's also worth noting, I used `2` as the length for the [STUFF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to account for the space in your `' - '` delimiter. You can play around with the lengths and delimiters that you need by changing the arguments passed into the `STUFF` function.

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
      STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + ColName
         FROM sample_table b
         WHERE a.UniqueIDpercombination = b.UniqueIDpercombination
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS ColName,
      STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + ColValue
         FROM sample_table b
         WHERE a.UniqueIDpercombination = b.UniqueIDpercombination
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS ColValue,
     a.UniqueIDpercombination
FROM sample_table a
GROUP BY UniqueIDpercombination
ORDER BY UniqueIDpercombination
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wpaa0_Hj).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp (
ColName varchar (10),
ColValue varchar (10),
UniqueIDpercombination int
)

insert into #temp values ('KitiD',  'K89901',   1)
insert into #temp values ('Kit',    '00900',    1        )
insert into #temp values ('KitiD',  'L7865',    2    )
insert into #temp values ('Kit',    '00400',    2        )
insert into #temp values ('UPC',    '345234',   3    )
insert into #temp values ('UPN',    'AVF',  3        )

select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by uniqueIDpercombination order by uniqueIDpercombination) as rownum into #joinTable from #temp
```

step 1: if you want to use join table / single use

```
select distinct UniqueIDpercombination into #masterTable from #temp

select concat(b1.ColName,' - ',b2.ColName) ColName,CONCAT(b1.ColValue,' - ',b2.ColValue) ColValue,a.UniqueIDpercombination from #masterTable a
left join #joinTable b1 on a.UniqueIDpercombination = b1.UniqueIDpercombination and b1.rownum = 1
left join #joinTable b2 on a.UniqueIDpercombination = b2.UniqueIDpercombination and b2.rownum = 2
```

step 2: if you want to use loop / if the number of duplicate is not only 2 row

```
select cast(NULL as varchar) ColName, cast(NULL as varchar) ColValue,  UniqueIDpercombination into #masterTable1 from #temp
group by UniqueIDpercombination

declare @i int
set @i = 1

while @i <= (select max(rownum) from #joinTable)
begin
update a
set 
a.ColName = case when a.ColName is null then b.ColName else (case when b.ColName is null then a.ColName else concat(a.ColName,' - ',b.ColName)  end) end,
a.ColValue = case when a.ColValue is null then b.ColValue else (case when b.ColValue is null then a.ColValue else concat(a.ColValue,' - ',b.ColValue) end) end
from #masterTable1 a
left join #joinTable b on a.UniqueIDpercombination = b.UniqueIDpercombination and b.rownum = @i

set @i = @i +1
end
```

db <> fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/CQ3RSYCQ